# How to connect to Amazon RDS MySQL instance while preventing MITM attack

Tags: mysql, ssl, amazon-rds

I have an Amazon
RDS instance running MySQL.
I've created a user account, and I've configured
MySQL to require the use of SSL for all
logins to that account.

I want the MySQL client to be able
to authenticate the server, to
ensure that man-in-the-middle attacks cannot occur.
The MySQL command-line client has an option
for this, namely <kbd>--ssl-verify-server-cert</kbd>.
However, when I try it, 
I get the following, uninformative, error message:

```
  ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error
```

So this command works fine:

```
  mysql --host $RDS_host --user $username \
  --password=$password \
  --ssl-ca mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem -e '\s'
```

But if I add the option <kbd>--ssl-verify-server-cert</kbd>, I get the error message
that I've just quoted.
(By the way, the CA file was obtained from
https://rds.amazonaws.com/doc/mysql-ssl-ca-cert.pem.)

Is there any way to get this option to work?

In one way, it's not surprising that the option fails to work, since the
[Amazon documentation (use the right-hand frame)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBEngine.MySQL51.html)
states the following:

> The SSL support in Amazon RDS is strictly for encrypting the connection between your client
>     and your DB Instance; it should not be relied on for authenticating the server.

However, I don't see where the difficulty is, from Amazon's point of view.
It seems to me that it would be quite easy for them to configure their server so that
I could use <kbd>--ssl-verify-server-cert</kbd>.

Comment: If you are connecting from EC2, it may be more efficient (i.e. simpler and less overhead) to setup a DB security group for your RDS instance and only allow access from instances in a given security group. (In that way, traffic is effectively firewalled, limiting access to the RDS instance and avoiding the SSL overhead).

Comment: That would be ideal, but I don't want to force the client to have EC2 instances.

Comment: I'd think that would mean the `$RDS_host` you specify is different from the Common Name that the RDS server certification uses. Maybe try to see the common name the server uses by using `openssl s_client -connect $RDS_host:3306 2>/dev/null | grep CN`. You could also add a couple of -v to your mysql command; maybe that would output more useful information when it fails.